# Parse POST data containing square brackets in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webob

I'm writing a python webapp (on Google AppEngine, using webob) that should process a form containing a list of addresses.

To simplify, lets say the form contains these inputs:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="address[]" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="address[]" value="2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="address[]" value="3" />
  <input type="hidden" name="address[]" value="4" />
```

Now, Rails\PHP would parse this to a single 'address' value containing a list [1,2,3,4].
Is there a simple way to do this in Python?

Comment: http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html#query-post-variables

Answer (score 0):

from inside a RequestHandler method, `self.request.params.getall('address[]')` will return a list of the values. The [] is of no significance though, the fields could just as easily be named 'address'.

Comment: The `[]` is a PHP-ism that I wish people would stop using.

Comment: Please do not use `self.request.params`. `.params` may contain values from the query string as well, which could lead to abuse/XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: Nonsense. Regardless of where you accept incoming data you need to sanitise it. The query-string is no more or less dangerous than values encoded in a POST-body.

Answer (score 0):

WebOb uses something called a [`MultiDict`](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/api/multidict.html#webob.multidict.MultiDict). [`self.request.POST`](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/api/request.html#webob.request.BaseRequest.POST) will take an appropriately form encoded request and return a `MultiDict`.

From this `MultiDict` you can call `.getall()` with the name of a key, in this case your key would be "address[]".

To get a list of entries you would call:

```
self.request.POST.getall('address[]')
```

It is not required that you use `address[]` as the name as `MultiDict` doesn't use that to identify whether a key can exist multiple times or not.